# passing multiple JTextFields to a boolean method

Tags: java, methods, jtextfield

Method FourOfAKind is supposed to test 4 JTextFields and check if they all equal each other. Each JTextField excepts one number. When I press the ButtonListener the boolean method FourOfAKind doesn't respond, even if it returns false, when I enter numbers 5555 ex.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
/**
 */
public class MyPanel extends JPanel
{
    private JLabel inputLabel, outputLabel;
    private JButton button;
    private JTextField digit1, digit2, digit3, digit4;

    public MyPanel()
    {
        inputLabel = new JLabel ("Enter four one digit numbers between zero and 9");
        button = new JButton ("Result");
        outputLabel = new JLabel ("---");

        digit1 = new JTextField(1);
        digit1.addActionListener (new ButtonListener());

        digit2 = new JTextField(1);
        digit2.addActionListener (new ButtonListener());

        digit3 = new JTextField(1);
        digit3.addActionListener (new ButtonListener());

        digit4 = new JTextField(1);
        digit4.addActionListener (new ButtonListener());

        add(inputLabel);
        add(digit1);
        add(digit2);
        add(digit3);
        add(digit4);
        add(button);
        add(outputLabel);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,100));
        setBackground(Color.yellow);
    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent even)
        {
            int num1, num2, num3, num4;

            String text = digit1.getText();
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(text);

            String text2 = digit2.getText();
            num2 = Integer.parseInt(text2);

            String text3 = digit3.getText();
            num3 = Integer.parseInt(text3);

            String text4 = digit4.getText();
            num4 = Integer.parseInt(text4);

            if (fourOfAKind(num1, num2, num3, num4))
            outputLabel.setText ("four of a kind");
        }
    }

    public boolean fourOfAKind(int a, int b, int c, int d)
    {
        return (a == b && b == c && c == d);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `equals()` instead of `==`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ButtonListener needs to be added to the button only, so that it will be activated when you press the button and trigger the event.

You can remove 'digitN.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());` and instead use:

```
button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
```

Like that, you are instructing Java to listen to the button being pressed and not the text field (which will trigger it when pressing the `Enter` key)

Comment: Really helpful, it works now. So when I create the JTextField I add it to the actionlistener which is the button instead of adding the JTextField to itself?

Comment: When you add the ActionListener to the JTextField, it "listens" for the user to press `Enter`. To run the ActionListener when pressing a button, you need to add it directly to that button.

[This is the Java tutorial about adding ActionListeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html), though it uses AWT components, the same can be done for Swing components, since they are inherited after all.